# How do I make Bubble Columns in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing Minecraft 1.13 and I know how the new bubble columns work, but I don't know how to make them in compact spaces. I know how to use them in oceans but I want to make one in a 3 x 3 space. I just want to make a bubble column in a 3 x 3 column.

Answer (score 9):

You have two options:

1. **Magma block:** it's found in the nether or in ocean ravine, and when placed underwater creates a bubble stream that pulls you down.
2. **Soul sand:** it's found in the nether, and when placed underwater creates a lifting bubble stream.

Also, all blocks in your column must be source blocks, or the column will not work.

Comment: Doesn't the soul sand or magma block have to be placed under a water source block? That is, if placed under running or falling water, it would not generate a bubble column.

Comment: Yes. The common approach to creating source blocks in survival, is to place a single source on top using a bucket, a full solid block where magma or soulsand is to go, and build up the column using kelp plants. Another alternative is to build the column out of (regular) ice blocks and break them with a non-silktouch tool starting from top. Of course you can also create them using buckets of water but for longer columns it's an awful hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Placing a Block of soul sand or magma

Answer (score 1):

All you need to know to make a bubble column is that
soul sand makes stuff go up, and magma makes stuff go down.

Once you have soul sand or magma, all you have to do is place it underwater, then use your new bubble column!